# How to store what key of a JSON to be parsed by a script in another JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Suppose I have a JSON called jsondata.json:

```
{
  "apiURL": [
    {
      "name":"Target", 
      "url":"https://redsky.target.com/v2/plp/collection/13562231,14919690,13728423,14919033,13533833,13459265,14917313,13519319,13533837,14919691,13479115,47778362,15028201,51467685,50846848,50759802,50879657,13219631,13561421,52062271,14917361,51803965,13474244,13519318?key=eb2551e4accc14f38cc42d32fbc2b2ea&pricing_store_id=2088&multichannel_option=basics&storeId=321"
    },
    {
      "name":"Safeway",
      "url":"https://shop.safeway.com/bin/safeway/product/aemaisle?aisleId=1_23_2&storeId=1483"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to tell my script to retrieve data from the API the url contains as follows:

```
# Load JSON containing URLs of APIs of grocery stores
with open(json_data, 'r') as data_f:
    data_dict = json.load(data_f)

# Organize API URLs
for apiurl in data_dict['apiURL']:
    responses.append('')
    responses[index] = requests.get(apiurl['url'])
    responses[index].raise_for_status()
    storenames.append(apiurl['name'])
    index += 1
first_target_item = responses[0].json()['search_response']['items']['Item'][0]['title']
first_safeway_item = responses[1].json()['productsinfo'][0]['description']
```

As you can see, my current implementation requires me to manually enter to my script which key to parse from each API (last two lines). I want to eventually be able to retrieve information from a dynamic number of grocery stores, but each website stores data on their items in a different key of their API.

How can I automate the process (e.g. store the key to parse from in jsondata.json) so that I don't have to update my script every time I add a new grocery store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with modifying the jsondata.json you can keep an array like this:

```
{
  "name":"Target", 
  "accessKeys": ["search_response", "items", "Item", "0", "title"],
  "url":"https://redsky.target.com/v2/plp/collection/13562231,14919690,13728423,14919033,13533833,13459265,14917313,13519319,13533837,14919691,13479115,47778362,15028201,51467685,50846848,50759802,50879657,13219631,13561421,52062271,14917361,51803965,13474244,13519318?key=eb2551e4accc14f38cc42d32fbc2b2ea&pricing_store_id=2088&multichannel_option=basics&storeId=321",
}
```

In your python code:

```
keys=["search_response", "items", "Item", "0", "title"] #apiUrl['accessKeys']
target_item=responses[0].json()
for i in target_item:
    target_item=target_item[i]
```

You can automate more,

```
def get_keys(data, keys):
    for key in keys:
        data=data[key]
    return data
items=[]
for index, apiurl in enumerate(data_dict['apiURL']):
    responses.append('')
    responses[index] = requests.get(apiurl['url'])
    responses[index].raise_for_status()
    storenames.append(apiurl['name'])
    items.append(get_keys(responses[index].json(), apiUrl['accessKeys']))
```

Comment: How can I tell the script to look through a dynamic number of keys? In my example, Target has 5 access keys and Safeway has 3. It's clear to me that I would have an array of 5 and 3 keys in the json file, respectively, but how would my Python script know how many keys to search through?